# Powershell multithreading not working on cmd.exe

Tags: multithreading, powershell, cmd

I need to run some code in powershell using multi-thread, i have tested a simple snippet and it runs fine on a powershell console. however when i try to run on a cmd.exe the code doesnt execute and no error was thrown wondering what is going on? if someone you help on this.

sample code as follow

```
$throttleLimit = 10

$iss = [system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate]::CreateDefault()
$Pool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $throttleLimit, $iss, $Host)
$Pool.Open()

$ScriptBlock = {
param($id)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
Write-Host "Done processing ID $id"
[System.Console]::WriteLine("Done processing ID $id")
}

for ($x = 1; $x -le 40; $x++) {
$powershell = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock).AddArgument($x)
$powershell.RunspacePool = $Pool
$handle = $powershell.BeginInvoke()
}
```

my batch file code is as follow

```
powershell -Command .\multiT.ps1 2>&1
```

Comment: Why aren't you using [PowerShell Jobs](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849698.aspx) instead?

Answer (score 1):

In the ISE, the script finishes before the output from the threads starts to show up.  I added 
`start-sleep -sec 10`
to the end of the code and I get output from cmd now.  For some reason the output is doubled, though (as in, I get 2 lines for each thread).

Comment: its now showing on the console but like you said it has duplicate printout. i guess you were right the console exit before the thread finishes. thanks for the help, i will look into why showing duplicate results.